# highchart.js: how to remove empty axis on both ends of a chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

Area chart leaves a large amount of empty axis lying around. How do I make sure that the chart starts from the point the axis is drawn ?

Comment: Do you use categories or datetime xAxis type?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I use Categories.

Comment: Set the min value as 0.49 and max as length of categories - 1.49. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/co962bza/

Comment: Beautiful! what are those values for ?

Comment: This is kind of workaround, which apply extremes in half of category to reduce the spacing.